# Can't connect to localhost SQL server 2012 with php

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, localhost

Hi I have a big problem with php connection to my local database.

I'm running:
Windows Server 2008 sp 1.
SQL server 2012.
My SQL server name: LRE-XP-VS2003\SQLEXPRESS. (status is running)

This is how I'm trying to connect

```
$server = 'localhost'; //or 127.0.0.1
$login = 'sa';
$passwd = 'my_passwd';
$database = 'ms4033';
$port = '49717';

$con = mysqli_connect ( $server , $login, $passwd, $database, $port );

if (!$con) {
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
 }
```

Result I get is spinning the loading button in browser and after long time "Internal Server Error - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout"

For the port number I checked in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and also directly in database

```
 USE master
 GO
 XP_READERRORLOG 0, 1, N'Server is listening'
 GO
```

and in SQL server Configuration manager too.
Without port number I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" or "Connection error: 2002"

I tried diseable my Firewall and it did not help.

I'm running asp .net too and paradoxically the connection is working properly
with this:

```
<add key="connectionString" value="server=LRE-XP-VS2003\SQLEXPRESS;database=ms4033;packet size=4096;user id=sa;password=my_passw" />
```

Am I missing something?

And what's difference between `$server = 'localhost';` or `$server = 'LRE-XP-VS2003\SQLEXPRESS';` ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) article. You need to use MS SQL connection, not the MYSQL

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>*
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that the function sqlsrv_connect(); will be the best option for me. It doesn't work yet. But I hope it will be soon :-)

Comment: Finally! I downgraded my php to php5.3. Downloaded sqlsrv .dlls from Microsoft. (it supports only phps5.3 or less) and it appears to be working :-)